# Arguments to constructor c++

Tags: c++, constructor, arguments

```
class Stack{
    public:
    explicit Stack(int  = 10){cout << "constructor called";}
    int size;
    int top;
    };
```

What does `(int  = 10)` do in this class?

This compiles and runs, for sure, but I don't know what effect it actually has or what the purpose is. I saw it in the Dietel and Dietel C++ book.

Answer (score 1):

It's a default argument with a value of `10`. The name is optional. What use it has in this case is unknown also.